# jQuery problem with jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I have an html page with jqgrid. This jqgrid retrieve data from a php script in json format.
My problem is that if I go on this jqgrid, clicking on "Imprese" all the page become only readable and not clickable. You can see the problem here:

```
http://mongolera.dyndns.biz/projects/gestionalePreventivi/index.html
```

I have no idea about what ca be the mistake.
Can you help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the strange HTML element

```
<btnMailControl style="">Check</btnMailControl>
```

which you use? Probably you want to change it to

```
<button id="btnMailControl">Check</button>
```

Your main problem is that under URL `/projects/gestionalePreventivi/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js` you can't load `grid.locale-en.js` which is important for the work of jqGrid.

I strict recommend you to include `<!DOCTYPE html ...` at the beginning of the page. See [her](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid#html_file)e an example.

Comment: bmtMail control is a button definend wirh jquery. grid.locale-en.js is present in that directory and i have already included it. The problem persist.

Comment: @michele: First of all you should always use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` to be able to debug the problem. Moreover I **don't see that you included `ui.jqgrid.css` on the page**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use firebug, because you are getting the following error:

```
b.jgrid.formatter is undefined
```

Comment: i have added grid-locale-it.js but the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have marked "Formatter" module while downloading jqGrid script (http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6). This error usually appears when the module is not there.